# how to push list of object value into array in angular4

Tags: angular

employeeView() method will get the list of employee data as an object,i want to store each object data into array

```
constructor(private userService: employeeviewservices) {    
         this.userService.employeeView().subscribe(data => this.EmployeeData=data),    
         this.EmployeeData.forEach(i=>{ 
         this.resultArray.push(
         {
             "id":i.id,    
             "name":i.name,
         });

       });
```

Comment: Just do it within subscribe callback

Comment: move the `forEach` inside the `subscribe`

Comment: just a comment apart for this, also use takewhile(falg) with subscribe and in onDestroy method set flag to false, otherwise your subscriber will be alive leading to memory leak in application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code:

```
constructor(private userService: employeeviewservices) {
  let newData: any= [];
  this.userService.employeeView().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
    newData = data.map(d: any => {
      return {
             "id":d.id,    
             "name":d.name,
         };
    });
    this.resultArray = newData;
 });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Do it inside the subscribe.

```
constructor(private userService: employeeviewservices) {
        this.userService.employeeView().subscribe(data => {
            this.EmployeeData = data;

            this.EmployeeData.forEach(i => {
                    this.resultArray.push({
                        "id": i.id,
                        "name": i.name,
                    });

                }),

        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers below are the same and are right. The proper way to solve your issue is to do the push of the array inside the suscribe.
Nontheless I feel the need to explain why. 
The suscription to the event "userService.employeeView()" is asyncronic. Which means that it will wait until the request ends to run the suscription method (which populates your array). 
In your code you are saying "whenever employeeView ends, do this (populate my array)" and right after that "please tell me, what do we have in this array?" and it will be none. Beacause the array is not populated yet.